# deleting spaces between every other column

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a large dataset that looks like this:

```
ID224912 A A A B B A B A B A B
```

and I want to make it look like:

```
ID224912 AA AB BA BA BA BA
```

I have tried modifying this code that I found somewhere else but no  success:

```
AWK=''' { printf (""%s %s %s %s"", $1, $2, $3, $4); } 
{ for (f = 5; f <= NF; f += 2) printf (""%s %s"", $(f), $(f + 1)); } 
{ printf (""\n""); } ''' 
awk ""${AWK}"" InFile > OutFile
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: That is terrible awk code embedded in terrible shell code. Wherever you found it, don't go back there!

Comment: What do you want when you have two spaces between two fields? Should it be considered as one space of is there an empty field that has to be joined with his brother? 
`id A  after2spaces C` => `id A after2spacesC` or => `id Aafter2spaces`

Comment: Perhaps add a clarification: I think your actual fields can be langer than 1 character and can have digits inside. Some `sed` solutions might be incorrect using this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/((\S+\s\S+\s)*\S+).*/\1/g;s/(\S+\s\S+)\s/\1/g' file
```

The solution is in two parts. First group the spaces between fields to be an even number and delete an extra field if there is one. Then group the fields

Comment: Nice! It is still unclear what should happen when a field is empty (what would look like two spaces between two fields)

Comment: It works well, but I do not understand. Can you explain how the grouping of the fields work? Why is the `\s` between the fields `\S+` and `\S+` removed, it seems to be part of the matched field. And why do you have the `\s` after the match, I would expect that you want to join 2 fields after a space.

Answer (score 0):

- You do not have to assign the AWK script into a variable. Just invoke it inline, which is simpler and safer.
- It looks strange that you are grouping the first four fields. As far as I can see from your desired output, it would be enough just to treat the first (ID) field separately.

Try something like:

```
awk '{printf("%s", $1); for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) printf(" %s%s", $i, $(i+1)); print ""}' InFile > OutFile
```

Hope this hepls.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{r=$1; for (i=2; i<NF; i+=2) r=r OFS $i $(i+1); print r}' file
ID224912 AA AB BA BA BA
```

Answer (score 0):

For funsies here is a sed solution:

```
cat input | sed 's/\([ A-Z ]\) \([ A-Z ]\)/\1\2/g' > output
```

Just for clarification I tested on BSD sed.

Comment: or `sed -i 's/\([ A-Z ]\) \([ A-Z ]\)/\1\2/g' infile` just to make it in-place

Comment: Looking at the code the OP gave, he wants to paste fields from field 2 and higher. The fields might be longer than 1 letter.

Comment: Also be aware that the last field should be deleted, when it can't be paired. That is why the next "solution" is incorrect: `sed -r 's/(^[^ ]* | )([^ ]*) ([^ ]*)/\1\2\3/g' input`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding **InFile** as your input file, you can use sed this way:

```
cat InFile |sed -e 's/\([a-zA-Z]\)[ \t]\([a-zA-Z]\)/\1\2/g'
```

N.B.: with the specified InFile in your initial question (with an odd count of letters), the result is:

```
ID224912 AA AB BA BA BA B
```

Answer (score 0):

The following [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) line

```
awk '{printf $1}{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) printf OFS $i $(i+1); print "" }'
```

will output

```
ID224912 AA AB BA BA BA B
```

As you notice, we have an extra column `B` in the end due to the even amount of columns in the original output. As the OP does not want this, we can fix this with a simple update in the for-loop condititions

```
awk '{printf $1}{for(i=2;i<NF;i+=2) printf OFS $i $(i+1); print "" }'
```

will output

```
ID224912 AA AB BA BA BA
```